# i18n and struts 1.3

Tags: internationalization, struts1

I would to internationalize my web app for multiple locales.

I've found several examples, like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-internationalizing-or-localization-example/).

They work, but in that cases it is displayed always the same page (that is if the user changes the language in any page, he/she is redirected to the home page for example).

I would that if the user clicks on a country flag (the html:link code is in a jsp file included by all the others jsp), the page (in which the user is) is reloaded.
How could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example link is clear: When the country flag is selected, the link goes to your "LanguageAction", set the Locale like this:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.FRANCE);
```

Finally, redirect the page back to the last viewed page. This will require you get the request URL before changing Locale.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So I have not to use `return mapping.findForward("success");`, have I? Could you give a redirect example or a link? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at Struts [`ActionRedirect`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionRedirect.html) (which extends `ActionForward`). [Example](http://javahelpline.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/forwarding-to-action-with-url-parameter-in-struts/).

Comment: I save the url before setting the locale with `request.getHeader("Referer")` and then I use `return new ActionRedirect(url)`. It works, but I don't obtain the wished result, if the jsp page is the result of a servlet execution or if the params are passed via post. Should I get the url in another way or?.